# Derivation of Energy-Mass Equivalence: Total energy = kinetic energy $+ mc^2$

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, mass, mass-energy

How do you derive the energy mass equivalence just from special relativity? To be exact, in this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZ8G4VKoSpQ, at around 23 minutes in, he claims that the total energy is equal to the Kinetic energy $+ mc^2$, which I don't understand how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relativistic kinetic energy: different definitions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/307464/)

Comment: You should try reading Einstein's original paper deriving the result. It is very accessible. https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/e_mc2.pdf.

Comment: See the answers to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525657/

Answer (score 2):

> he claims that the total energy is equal to the Kinetic energy + mc^2, which I don't understand how.

The total energy of a free particle (no potential energy) is *defined* as the kinetic energy plus the rest energy $mc^2$, where $m$ is the *rest mass*.

The total energy, in terms of the rest mass $m$ is:
$$
E = \gamma m c^2\;,
$$
where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ and $v$ is the velocity.

We then *define* the kinetic energy as:
$$
KE = E - mc^2 = (\gamma - 1)mc^2\;,
$$

This definition make sense because in the non-relativistic limit ($v<<c$), we have:
$$
\gamma \approx 1 + \frac{v^2}{2c^2}\;.
$$

So that, in the non-relativistic limit, we also have:
$$
KE \approx (1 + \frac{v^2}{2c^2} - 1)mc^2 = \frac{1}{2}mv^2\;,
$$
as expected.

---

If you are interested in where
$$
E = \gamma m c^2
$$
comes from to begin with, you can consider the possible classical actions for a free relativistic particle.

There is only one relativistic invariant that could make up the action. We must have
$$
S = \alpha \int ds\;,
$$
where $ds$ is the world line and $\alpha$ is a constant (to be determined below). So we have
$$
S = \alpha \int dt \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu}\;.
$$

In other words the Lagrangian is:
$$
L = \alpha \sqrt{c^2 - v^2}\;,
$$
which must reduce to $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ when $v<<c$.

This means that:
$$
\alpha = -mc
$$

This means that:
$$
L = -mc^2\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} = -mc^2/\gamma\;.
$$

Now we can turn the usual crank to get the Hamiltonian (another name for the energy).

First, we see that (by definition):
$$
p \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial v} = mv\gamma
$$

So we have (by the usual relation between the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian):
$$
E = pv - L = \gamma m (v^2 + \frac{c^2}{\gamma^2}) = \gamma m c^2\;.
$$

And, again, to be clear, I am using the symbol $m$ to mean the *rest mass*.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the total energy, like it is usually done as $E=mc^2$ the kinetic energy ist $KE=mc^2-m_0c^2$ where m is the relativistic mass $m_0$ the mass of a particle without kinetic energy. The m in the video ist what is usually called $m_0$